# Linkedin People Search Javascript API not returning any result

Tags: javascript, api, search, linkedin-api

I'm using the linkedin `JS API`

I'm trying to perform `people search`, It's not returning anything

Code :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
        api_key: --my api key--
        onLoad: onLinkedInLoad
        authorize: true
</script> 

<script type="text/javascript">

        function onLinkedInLoad() {
            IN.Event.on(IN, "auth", onLinkedInAuth);
        }

        function onLinkedInAuth() {

            IN.API.PeopleSearch()
            .fields("firstName", "lastName", "distance")
            .params({"company-name":"infosys"})
            .result(displayPeopleSearch)
            .error(displayPeopleSearchError);

        }

        function displayPeopleSearch(){

            var peopleSearchDiv = document.getElementById("peoplesearch");

            var members = peopleSearch.people.values;


            for (var member in members) {
            // but inside the loop, everything is the same
            // extract the title from the members first position
                peopleSearchDiv.innerHTML += "<p>" + members[member].firstName + " " + members[member].lastName + " is a " + members[member].positions.values[0].title + ".</p>";

            }
        }
```

Any help, anything I'm doing wrong?

I'm following this [tutorial](http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/javascript-api-tutorial)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On this line you are using a variable `peopleSearch` that is not declared anywhere:

```
var members = peopleSearch.people.values;
```

You must add a parameter to the function `function displayPeopleSearch()`

```
function displayPeopleSearch(peopleSearch){

        var peopleSearchDiv = document.getElementById("peoplesearch");

        var members = peopleSearch.people.values;


        for (var member in members) {
        // but inside the loop, everything is the same
        // extract the title from the members first position
            peopleSearchDiv.innerHTML += "<p>" + members[member].firstName + " " + members[member].lastName + " is a " + members[member].positions.values[0].title + ".</p>";

        }
    }
```

d.

Comment: Oh, stupid stupid mistake, thanks for pointing it out @Didier!